# jsf variable lost value

Tags: variables, jsf, view-scope

I have a managed Bean called `bean1.java` that has a boolean var called `found`. The variable says if a client has been found or not.

The bean has a method `validate()` that goes to the DB and checks if the client exists, and sets the variable to  `found=true` if it exists or 'false' if it doesn't.

Then I keep completing other fields in my form. Now, when I click the button save, it the method `saving()`. That method has to do an action if the var `found` is true and another action if it's false.

But the problem is when I validate the variable that has been set to true on the method `validate()`, now it has the value "false".

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped //SessionScoped
    public class AgregarPoliza implements Serializable{

    public boolean found=false; 


    public void validate(){
    // go to data base and validate if the client exist, when exist
    // set variable true
    found = true;  // setFound(true); <--- i already try this way too
   }

    public void saving(){

    //it has two actions to do but need to know the value of found
     System.out.println("my var found has" + found); //this system.out shows false
     if(found ==true){
      //makes an action
      }
     else{
     //makes another action
      }


    }

//get and set of the value found            


    }
```

Comment: Please show your JSF page as well and correct the typos in your bean java code.

Comment: The only reason why `found=false` again is when the bean is being recreated. Verify that the bean is not being destroyed and recreated by adding some logging in a constructor for the bean.

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling the validate method in the method saving like this.

```
public void validate()
{

// go to data base and validate if the client exist, when exist
// set variable true
found = true;  // setFound(true); <--- i already try this way too
}

public void saving(){
  this.validate();
//it has two actions to do but need to know the value of found
 System.out.println("my var found has" + found); //this system.out shows false
 if(found ==true){
  //makes an action
  }
 else{
 //makes another action
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i hava use this and this is working fine now check it please now it can not lost value...

```
AgregarPoliza.java

package com.best.uibeansTest;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name = "agregarPoliza")
@SessionScoped
public class AgregarPoliza implements Serializable{

public boolean found=false; 


public void validate(){
// go to data base and validate if the client exist, when exist
// set variable true
found = true;  // setFound(true); <--- i already try this way too
}

public String saving(){
    validate();
//it has two actions to do but need to know the value of found
 System.out.println("my var found has" + found); //this system.out shows false
 if(found ==true){
  //makes an action
  }
 else{
 //makes another action
  }

return "test2.xhtml" ;
}
//get and set of the value found            
public boolean isFound() {
    return found;
}

public void setFound(boolean found) {
    this.found = found;
}

//get and set of the value found            


}
```

here i just get agregarPoliza as bean i am showing jsf code below through which i check this..

```
test2.xhtml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"    
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <head>
      <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
   </head>
   <h:body>
   <h2>Result</h2>
   <hr />
   <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="false" action="#{agregarPoliza.saving}"/>
      |
      found value:
      #{agregarPoliza.found}
   </h:form>

   </h:body>
</html>
```

on clicking of save button found value is changed to true. try this..